# Receving Message received Acknwoledgement From GCM Service

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing `PUSH NOTIFICATION` in `Android`. They work fine. However, they are not delivered timely. Therefore I am trying to figure out the time taken to deliver the sent message by my server to `GCM` service and the time taken by `GCM` Service to deliver the message to my application.

I confirmed that my server successfully sent the message. Is there any way to figure out that `GCM` service received the message and put it in its Queue for delivery? In other words, can we get an acknowledgement once the message is received by GCM service regardless whether they are delivered to the application or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The acknowledgement you get from the GCM service only tells you the message has been received by the GCM service, regardless to it being delivered to the application or not. You will get it even if the device on which the application is installed is turned off.

If you want to get an acknowledgement when the message is delivered to the application, you must call your server from your application when it receives the message. You can include some unique identifier in your message, and send that identifier from your application to your server to acknowledge delivery.

Comment: Hi Eran, if I need to call my server from application, What should my app do ? Do we have to run a background service and check for notifications or is there a way to hook up to the notification receive event ?